# remove slash from jsonstring jackson lib java

Tags: java

I have large json string something like this:

```
[{\"name\":\"Nick\",\"role\":\"admin\",\"age\":\"32\",\"rating\":47}]
```

I want to remove every occurrence of \" with " in string.

for this i used String's `relaceAll("\\"","\"")
when i am print the string after replace its printing fine but when i am sending string to object in json. its appending slash , please guide me how to get rid of this slash

My expecting result:

```
[{"name":"Nick","role":"admin","age":"32","rating":47}]
```

Comment: Are you _certain_ that the slash isn't just escaping the double-quote?

Comment: @MartinParkin yes

Comment: @Ron Please [edit] your question to include the source code how you generate the string and how you "send string to object in json". Actually, post a [mcve] of your problem, which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1):

> For this i used String's `relaceAll("\\"","\"")` ...

The [String#replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method interprets the argument as a [**RegEx**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) (Regular Expression). The Backslash Character (**\**) is an escape character in both String & Regex.

Hence, you need to double-escape it for the RegEx to work.

**Example:**

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

You can also use [String#replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method to perfrom the same task like this:

```
myString = myString.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Comment: thank your response but struggle is writing string to jsonnode there its appending \